# Is there an option to log console output from package installation executed by kickstart?

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, selinux, kickstart

I've built an ISO on top of CentOS 6 minimal that bundles some additional packages. Generally it works great, but some recent change I've made has broken it a little: the SELinux module I'm allegedly installing from the `%post` section of one of my RPMs is showing as *not* having been installed once the newly-commission machine boots up. Now running the same code from the console successfully installs the SELinux module, so I'm a little stuck.

In order to debug this, I'd to see output from when the packages were installed, hoping to catch some clue on *stderr* or somesuch. Unfortunately, the graphical installation GUI doesn't provide any such information, and switching screens in VirtualBox to e.g. the anaconda shell hasn't revealed anything useful either.

Is there an option I can put in my kickstart config file to save the actual output of the entire RPM installation process, or some other way to diagnose this kind of problem?

Comment: I sort of gave up and rebuilt everything with logging-to-file sprinkled around my RPM's `%post` section. This file can then be examined from the anaconda shell, or from the normal shell after first boot. Still think there may be value in this question though, if there's a "better" approach more generally, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: You can log to a file with `%post --log=/mylog`. Look for installation logs in `/root`.

Comment: @meuh: Packages aren't installed by the `%post` section (well, unless you do so manually from within that script, but that's not what I'm trying to test!). I already have `%post` logging.